# Transformation of $\log(X)+\log(1-X)$, where $X$ is uniform.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, problem-solving

I am trying to calculate the variance of:
$$\log(X)+\log(1-X)$$
where $X \sim \mathrm{Unif}(0,1)$.

So far, I have tried to use a random variable transformation, i.e. define $Y=\log(X)+\log(1-X)$, then:
$$X_1=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4e^Y}}{2}$$
$$X_2=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4e^Y}}{2}$$
Then I got the density, which is (same for both $X_1$ and $X_2$:
$$f_Y(y)=\frac{e^y}{\sqrt{1-4e^y}}$$
And now, I can calculate the variance of that through the integral:
$$Var[Y]=\int^{-2\log(2)}_{-\infty}dy\ y^2\frac{e^y}{\sqrt{1-4e^y}}-\bigg(\int^{-2\log(2)}_{-\infty}dy\ y\frac{e^y}{\sqrt{1-4e^y}}\bigg)^2$$

Comment: Little remark: The density should be $f_Y(y)=2\frac{e^y}{\sqrt{1-4e^y}}$ instead of $f_Y(y)=\frac{e^y}{\sqrt{1-4e^y}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
Y=\log(X)+\log(1-X)\ .
$$
By definition
$$
\langle Y^2\rangle=\int_0^1 dx\, (\log(x)+\log(1-x))^2=8-\pi^2/3
$$
and
$$
\langle Y\rangle^2=\left[\int_0^1 dx \, (\log(x)+\log(1-x))\right]^2=4\ .
$$
Therefore, $\operatorname{Var}(Y)=4-\pi^2/3$.

Comment: Brilliant. I can't even understand why I couldn't do it that simply.

Comment: @marco11 Take in general $Y=f(X)$. Then the pdf of $Y$ is $p_Y(y)=\int_{\sigma_X}dx\ p_X(x)\delta(y-f(x))$, where $\sigma_X$ is the *support* of $X$ and $p_X(x)$ is the pdf of the 'original' variable $X$. Then the second moment of $Y$ is by definition $\langle Y^2\rangle=\int_{\sigma_Y}dy\ y^2 p_Y(y)=\int_{\sigma_Y}dy\ y^2 \int_{\sigma_X}dx\ p_X(x)\delta(y-f(x))$. Exchanging integrals and killing the $y$-integral with the Dirac delta, you obtain $\langle Y^2\rangle=\int_{\sigma_X}dx p(x)[f(x)]^2$...easy, right?

Comment: What is the Dirac delta and why do we have $dx$ before the integral's expression?

Comment: @marco11 OK, if you haven't yet encountered the Dirac delta, please ignore my comment...when you'll meet it, you will see that it makes life so much easier when setting up pdf calculations.

Comment: I will definitely read about it. Could you just please tell me whether $dx$ before the expression makes any difference?

Comment: I mean $dx$ before the expression in the integral (as in your answer), rather than at the end of it.

Comment: @marco11 It makes no difference. $\int dx f(x)$ or $\int f(x)dx$ mean exactly the same thing.